# TypeError: can't pickle _thread.RLock objects KerasClassifier

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, scikit-learn

I am trying to make an ensemble of 2 Tensorflow Keras Models.

Model 1:

```
model = Sequential(
    [
        Input(shape=(28,28,1)),
        Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation="relu"),
        MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
        Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation="relu"),
        MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
        Flatten(),
        Dropout(0.5),
        Dense(10, activation="softmax"),
    ]
)

#model.summary()
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['acc', 'mse'])
history = model.fit(X_train_norm, y_train_ohe, batch_size=256, epochs=20, verbose=2, validation_data=(X_test_norm,y_test_ohe))
```

Model 2:

```
model2 = Sequential(
    [
        Input(shape=(28,28,1)),
        Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation="relu"),
        MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
        Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation="relu"),
        MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
        Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation="relu"),
        MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
        Flatten(),
        Dropout(0.5),
        Dense(10, activation="softmax"),
    ]
)
model2.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['acc'])
hist = model2.fit(X_train_norm, y_train_ohe, batch_size=512, epochs=10, verbose=2, validation_data=(X_test_norm, y_test_ohe))
```

Now to combine these 2 models for ensemble, I thought to create them as sklearn models via wrapper, and use them on voting classifiers like [this](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2018/06/comprehensive-guide-for-ensemble-models/).

My Code:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import VotingClassifier
from tensorflow.keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier
myModel = KerasClassifier(build_fn=model)
myModel2 = KerasClassifier(build_fn=model2)
from sklearn.multiclass import OneVsRestClassifier

ensemModel = OneVsRestClassifier(VotingClassifier(estimators=[('cnn', model), ('lstm',model2)]))


ensemModel.fit(X_train_norm, y_train_ohe)
```

But I am getting this error:

```
TypeError: can't pickle _thread.RLock objects
```

Comment: [OneVsRestClassifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.multiclass.OneVsRestClassifier.html) **requires** sklearn estimator object **not** Keras Model object. I think you simply can not do this.

Comment: It is giving error witout OneVsRestClassifier.

Comment: Which line of code does it throw that error?